# Estimation of power of received radio signal

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency, lienard-wiechert

I would like to estimate the magnitude of a radio signal received from a transmitter by first principles:

Transmitter antenna length $L=1$ m

Transmitter antenna cross-sectional area $A=1\hbox{ cm}^2$

Number of electrons per unit volume in antenna $n_e=10^{28}$

Radiation resistance of antenna $R_R=10\ \Omega$

Power radiated by transmitter $P_R=1$ kW

Frequency $f=100$ MHz

Joules law for the antenna: $P_R=I^2 R_R$

Current into transmitter antenna $I=\sqrt{\frac{P_R}{R_R}}=\sqrt{\frac{10^3}{10}}=10$ A

Current $I$ in transmitter antenna is related to the electron drift velocity $v_e$ by the relationship $I=v_e\ A\ n_e\ e$

$$v_e=\frac{I}{A\ n_e\ e}=\frac{10^1}{10^{-4}\ 10^{28}\ 10^{-19}}=10^{-4}\ \hbox{m/s}$$

Electron acceleration in transmitter $a_e=v_e f=10^{-4}\ 10^8=10^4\ \hbox{m/s}^2$

Total charge in the transmitter antenna $Q=L\ A\ n_e\ e = 10^0\ 10^{-4}\ 10^{28}\ 10^{-19}=10^5\hbox{ C}$.

Interestingly this is a very large number. For example the static charge $Q_S$ on a spherical electrode with radius $1$ m at a voltage of $1$ MV is just $Q_S=4\pi\epsilon_0 R V=10^{-10} 10^0 10^6 = 10^{-4}$ C.

Assume receiver antenna is at a distance $D=1$ km

The strength of the vertical electric field at the receiver, $E_{rec}$, is given by the far-field radiation formula

$$E_{rec}=\frac{Q\ a_e}{4\pi\epsilon_0\ c^2\ D}=\frac{10^5\ 10^4}{10^{-10}\ 10^{16}\ 10^3}=1\ \hbox{V/m}$$

If the receiver antenna also has length $L=1$ m and radiation resistance $R_R=10\ \Omega$ then the power it receives $P_{rec}$, according to Joule's law, is given by

$$P_{rec}=\frac{V_{rec}^2}{R_R}=\frac{(E_{rec}\ L)^2}{R_R}=\frac{1}{10}\hbox{W}$$

Have I got this approximately right?

If the transmitter antenna was omnidirectional at a distance of $1$ km the Energy flux should be $10^3/(4\pi\times10^6)=10^{-4}$ W/m$^2$.

Thus if the receiving antenna also has a length $1$ m and width $1$ cm I would have thought it should only intercept a power of $1\times 10^{-2} \times 10^{-4}=10^{-6}$ Watts.

Comment: A diagram showing what your various paramters mean might make your question more clear. For example, is *A* the cross sectional area of a wire being used to form a dipole antenna, or is it the area from which the antenna captures EM waves propagating past it?

Comment: The area $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the antenna.

Comment: It's still not clear. The cross section of the wire that makes up the antenna, or the cross section of the portion of the radiation that it captures.

Comment: The cross section of the wire that makes up the antenna.